# Value from input type='file' in form returns empty string

Tags: php, forms, drupal

Please help me with my problem: In my custom module `img_menu` I want to add a upload image field to edit menu form. It works, field shows up in the form, but when I upload an image and then I save form, `dpm` shows that `$form_state['values']['banner_upload']` is an empty string. Does anybody know why? Thank you.

```php
function img_menu_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'menu_edit_item') {
        $form['banner'] = array(
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            ...
         );

        $form['banner']['banner_upload'] = array(
            '#type' => 'file',
            '#title' => t('Upload a new banner image'),
            '#maxlength' => 40,
        );

        $form['#submit'][] = 'img_menu_form_submit';
    }
}

function img_menu_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    dpm($form_state['values']['banner_upload']);
}
```

Comment: Show us your html

Comment: I didn't write any HTML. I want to add an image upload field to menu link in primary menu. So I have a custom module and I generate a field... sorry, I am new. @Will

Comment: Problem solved :).

Comment: Other users may land in the same situation, it would be nice to share your solution instead of just saying "solved", the purpose of this site is to retrieve valuable knowledge, not unanswered question - or close it.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'll explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution is:**
I decided to change type of field from `file` to `managed_file` and now it works.

```php
function img_menu_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'menu_edit_item') {
        $form['banner'] = array(
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            ...
         );

        $form['banner']['banner_upload'] = array(
            '#type' => 'managed_file',
            '#title' => t('Upload a new banner image'),
            '#size' => 40,
            '#upload_location' => 'public://',
        );

        $form['#submit'][] = 'img_menu_form_submit';
    }
}

function img_menu_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['banner_upload']);
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);
    dpm($file->uri);
}
```

This way when I do `dpm($file->uri);` it works well, dpm shows path of uploaded image just like I wanted.